# changing text size of SCNText

Tags: text, scenekit, text-size

I'm trying to set the size of the font using this code:

```
func setupText(){
     let text = SCNText(string: "textString", extrusionDepth: 4)
        textNode.geometry = text
        textNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, -200, 5)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)
        text.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
        text.font = UIFont(name: "Helvatica", size: 30)
    }
```

I'm changing the size argument but my text doesn't get any bigger or smaller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In sceneKit distances are specified in meters. So text size should be 0.3 instead of 30.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the font size should work but maybe not as much as you would expect. This depends of the size of your 3d world.

Another way to scale up a 3d text is to scale its node:

```
textNode.scale = SCNVector3Make( scaleValue, scaleValue, scaleValue); //todo: make me swift
```

Comment: `SCNVector3Make` and semicolons are allowed in Swift, so no need for the TODO. :) (They are sort of against what seems to be preferred style, though.)

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work because the font isn't being set.  The font isn't being set because you misspelled "Helvetica" as "Helvatica".

Comment: Indeed, correcting the typo does the job. This is the correct answer!